# User is not authorized to perform: apigateway:GET on resource:

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, flutter-aws-amplify

I have created a simple AWS Amplify function (serverless function), and now I have created an API in order to interact with that Lambda function in my Flutter app. However, I am encountering an issue. Could anyone please guide me?

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 1]

I was expecting that the interaction between the Flutter app and the Lambda function would work seamlessly without any errors. The Lambda function should be invoked successfully when the Flutter app makes an API call.

Comment: Is that 1st error related to the user your logged into the conole, or a role associated with Lambda or API Gateway? In either case your issue seems IAM related, but without knowing how Lambda/APIGW/IAM is configured its difficult to suggest a fix. Does your API GW and Lambda log to CloudWatch Logs? If not enable them and review those logs, you might get a more useful error. Edit your question with your findings. Also, when possible paste errors as text not images - your making it harder to help you so some people will just ignore your question if they cany copy/paste text.